# Why does my generator hang instead of throwing exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a generator that returns lines from a number of files, through a filter. It looks like this:

```py
def line_generator(self):
    # Find the relevant files
    files = self.get_files()

    # Read lines
    input_object = fileinput.input(files)
    for line in input_object:

        # Apply filter and yield if it is not *None*
        filtered = self.__line_filter(input_object.filename(), line)
        if filtered is not None:
            yield filtered

    input_object.close()
```

The method `self.get_files()` returns a list of file paths or an empty list.
I have tried to do `s = fileinput.input([])`, and then call `s.next()`. This is where it hangs, and I cannot understand why. I'm trying to be pythonic, and not handling all errors myself, but I guess this is one where there is no way around. Or is there?

Unfortunately I have no means of testing this on Linux right now, but could someone please try the following on Linux, and comment what they get?

```
import fileinput
s = fileinput.input([])
s.next()
```

I'm on Windows with Python 2.7.5 (64 bit).

All in all, I'd really like to know:

Is this a bug in Python, or me that is doing something wrong?
Shouldn't .next() always return something, or raise a `StopIteration`?

Comment: What does it mean that the program "hangs?" How are you executing it? What's the output you see? What's the expected output you want? Also: "Is this a bug in Python, or me that is doing something wrong?" The answer is *always* the user doing something wrong. The chance to find a bug in Python are pretty slim, especially for "trivial" code like yours. You should simply ignore this possibility since it will only make you loose time thinking what kind of bug could it be.

Comment: I'm using IDLE to do everything. I have made som screenshots here: http://ge.tt/9dh4hqv
Snap1.png is after running the above commands. Snap2.png is the output when I press Ctrl+C to break it. Basically is just hangs in the state depicted by Snap1.png, unless you break it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) defaults to stdin if the list is empty, so it's just waiting for you to type something.

An obvious fix would be to get rid of `fileinput` (is not terribly useful anyway) and to be explicit, as python zen suggests:

```
for path in self.get_files():
    with open(path) as fp:
      for line in fp:
         etc
```

Comment: This is awesome! Got a 25% performance increase as well, in my preliminary tests. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As others already have answered, I try to answer one specific sub-item:

> Shouldn't `.next()` always return something, or raise a `StopIteration`?

Yes, but it is not specified when this return is supposed to happen: within some milliseconds, seconds or even longer.

If you have a blocking iterator, you can define some wrapper around it so that it runs inside a different thread, filling a list or something, and the originating thread gets an interface to determine if there are data, if there are currently no data or if the source is exhausted.

I can elaborate on this even more if needed.

Comment: No need, I get the point, but if you feel like it, go nuts :)